# Convert nvarchar to varchar in c# to mirror SQL's functionality

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I'm maintaining a legacy database and one of the tables has a primary key over three columns. Two of the columns are varchar(100)

Sometimes the system tries to insert data such as `F1501` and `Φ1501` from our datasource (which is correct). However, SQL it would appear doesn't support these values for a primary key, so it converts `Φ` to `F` silently and this creates a primary key conflict.

In my c# application, I want to check for duplicates, so I need a way to compare `Φ1501` to `F1501` to generate a match so that I can skip inserting it.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about converting the string in code to ASCII? To bytes: `byte[] unicode = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("stuff");` then `string ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(unicode);`?

Comment: This gave me `?♥1 5 0 1` hmm

Comment: Not sure what else you can realistically do other than convert the legacy database to use NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR. Stuffing unicode data into non-unicode columns is not really a good idea.

Comment: That was my first thought, however even if the column is nvarchar, because the column is a primary key the key is still stored as plain ascii (it would seem, from my tests)

Comment: Ideally your primary key shouldn't be any kind of VARCHAR/NVARCHAR and would be better served as a UNIQUE constraint. But, my guess would be that there was something not right in your test.

Comment: I completely agree, you should see what else is wrong with this legacy database...! Ours is not to reason why...

Comment: Oh the joy of legacy. Those systems that we "will replace one day".....

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: `String.Normalize`

`Console.WriteLine("Φ1501".Normalize());`

> Output:
>
> F1501